# QGIS Installation Extract Error

Tags: qgis, installation

I'm attempting to install QGIS version 2.18.6 (64-bit).  The installation gets close to completion, but before it finishes I get a message saying "Extract error writing to file..." I've tried installing several times, and a different file name comes up in the error message almost everytime (including qtgui4.dll, gdal200.dll, and others).  Per another user's suggestion, I opened a command window and looked at the tasklist, but nothing comes up.  I'm running as an admin and installing to the default program files (C:/Program Files).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe [this](/questions/152873/how-to-completely-uninstall-and-remove-qgis-2-8-1) post could help.

Comment: Thanks for this.  This post helped me resolve the issue.  Once I went into regedit and searched for "qgis" I found several folders (not necessarily named "qgis" but with qgis files in them) and deleted.  After restarting my computer I was able to successfully install the program.